# Can I send a Whatsapp message in python when a condition == True without defining a specific time?

Tags: python, selenium

```
import pywhatkit as pwk

pwk.sendwhatmsg("phone_number", "Automated message", 10, 0)
```

I have this code but I want to send a message without setting a specific time.

Comment: put a `while True` loop around it and check the condition every x seconds?

Answer (score 0):

Didn't find any way to do this using **pywhatkit**.

A solution I found is to use **pyautogui** on **WhatsApp Web**, selecting the message input box.

The program types the message and presses enter:

```
import pyautogui
import time

def send_msg(msg):
    pyautogui.typewrite(msg)
    time.sleep(0.1)
    pyautogui.press("enter")

send_msg("Hello, world")
```

Answer (score 0):

## use sendwhatmsg_instantly

pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg_instantly(phone_no="+911111111111", message="This is a instant message.")